# Compare last row to previous row by group and populate new column

Tags: sql, sas, window-functions, proc-sql

I need to compare the last row of a group to the row above it, see if changes occur in a few columns, and populate a new column with 1 if a change occurs.  The data presentation below will explain better.

Also need to account for having a group with only 1 row.

what we have:

```
 Group    Name     Sport     DogName   Eligibility 
   1      Tom      BBALL     Toto        Yes
   1      Tom      BBall     Toto        Yes
   1      Tom      golf      spot        Yes
   2     Nancy     vllyball  Jimmy       yes
   2     Nancy     vllyball  rover       no
```

what we want:

```
 Group    Name     Sport     DogName   Eligibility N_change  S_change  D_Change  E_change
     1      Tom      BBALL     Toto        Yes      0           0        0       0
     1      Tom      BBall     Toto        Yes      0           0        0       0
     1      Tom      golf      spot        Yes      0           1        1       0
     2     Nancy     vllyball  Jimmy       yes      0           0        0       0
     2     Nancy     vllyball  rover       no       0           0        1       1
```

Only care about changes from row to row within group. Thank you for any help in advance.

The rows are already ordered so we only need to last two of the group. If it is easier to compare sequential rows in a group then that is just as good for my purposes.

I did know this would be arrays and I struggle with these because never use them for my typical sas modeling.  Wanted to keep things short and sweet.

Comment: To get the "row above it" you'll need to specify a row ordering. Which one is it?

Comment: whoops, the rows are already ordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the data step and lag statements. Ensure your data is sorted by group first, and that the rows within groups are sorted in the correct order. Using arrays will make your code much smaller.

The logic below will compare each row with the previous row. A flag of 1 will be set only if:

1. It's not the first row of the group
2. The current value differs from the previous value.

The syntax `var = (test logic);` is a shortcut to automatically generate dummy flags.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by group;

    array var[*]        name sport dogname eligibility;
    array lagvar[*] $   lag_name lag_sport lag_dogname lag_eligibility;
    array changeflag[*] N_change S_change D_change E_change;

    do i = 1 to dim(var);
        lagvar[i]     = lag(var[i]);
        changeflag[i] = (var[i] NE lagvar[i] AND NOT first.group);
    end;
  
   drop lag: i;
run;
```

Comment: I changed the 'lag' in the drop statement to 'var' and changed the first dim(vars) to dim(var).  I'm getting an error that the subscript is out of range, not sure if it is my data

Comment: I forced the lagvar array to be character using the $ symbol. See if that helps.

Comment: same error.  even forced upcase and striped blank spaces rerloading data. It also doesnt recognize anything in the drop statement, I've tried lag and var.

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon for procedural programmers to find this kind of dilemma in SQL, which is predominately a set language where rows have no position.  If you write a procedure that reads the select data (sorted in the desired order), it can have variables to control creating the desired additional columns in the output, similar to the lag function above.

Or you can put it into a spreadsheet, which is happier detecting the changes in formula filled columns =if(a2<>a1,1,0).  Just make sure nobody re-sorts the spreadsheet data into a new order!

Comment: the spreadsheet idea is nice, unfortunately there are thousands of groups that need this done.

Comment: What's the final product?  If you put it in a table, it stops making sense unless sorted right.